# Name and Summary Missing from Messages

Tags: messages

My wife did something to messages and it left only the picture for each conversation and it removed the name and summary.  We have gone so far as to reboot her Macbook but we can't get it back to normal.  Here is an image of how her Messages looks now.

[image]

Any one know how to get her back to normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your mouse cursor on the line that separates left column where are the conversation listing and the right column – the conversation window (the red arrow on the picture below). When the cursor changes to left/right arrows separated by | – just press left mouse button and drag it to the right expanding left column and bringing back the info you are missing now.
[image]